# python nested for loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like the inner for loop to give me one value and goes on to the next iteration for each outer loop. Appreciate your responds.

Currently the result:

- Personal NameJohn
- Personal NamePeter
- Personal Name123456
- ID #John
- ID #Peter
- ID #123456
- Emergency contactJohn
- Emergency contactPeter
- Emergency contact123456

Result should just be:

- ID #123456
- Personal NameJohn
- Emergency contactPeter

  ```
  employees={'ID #','Personal Name','Emergency contact'}

  excel={'123456',
     'John',
     'Peter'}

  for key in employees:
      for value in excel:
         print(key + value)
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `zip` to iterate over two objects at the same time.

note: you are using sets (created using `{"set", "values"}`) here. Sets have no order, so you should use lists (created using `["list", "values"]`) instead.

```
for key, value in zip(employees, excel):
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: >>> type({'a','b'})
<class 'set'>

Comment: what I meant is that using `{}` creates a set instead of a list

Comment: `val = {}` creates and empty dictionary, not set. For an empty set, use `val = set()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` after changing the type of your input data. Sets order their original content, thus producing incorrect pairings:

```
employees=['ID #','Personal Name','Emergency contact']
excel=['123456', 'John','Peter']
new_data = [a+b for a, b in zip(employees, excel)]
```

Output:

```
['ID #123456', 'Personal NameJohn', 'Emergency contactPeter']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use square brackets `[]` instead of curly brackets `{}`. Then you could use `zip()` (see other answers) or use something very basic like this:

```
for i in range(len(employees)):
    print(employees[i], excel[i])
```

Comment: Indeed, I've changed it (I'm not native english)